# Replace NA with previous mean (cumean)

Tags: r, mean, lag, imputation

I'd like some help to compute lag mean of a column just if a value is NA

Follow the example

```
library(tidyverse)
 
iname <- rep('a', 10)
itime <- 1:10 
ival <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, NA, 8, 9, 10)
ds <- tibble(iname, itime, ival)
ds
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   iname itime  ival
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 a         1     1
 2 a         2     2
 3 a         3     3
 4 a         4    NA
 5 a         5     5
 6 a         6     6
 7 a         7    NA
 8 a         8     8
 9 a         9     9
10 a        10    10 
ds %>%
    group_by(iname) %>%
    mutate(...) -> result
result
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   iname itime  ival
   <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 a         1  1   
 2 a         2  2   
 3 a         3  3   
 4 a         4  2   
 5 a         5  5   
 6 a         6  6   
 7 a         7  3.16
 8 a         8  8   
 9 a         9  9   
10 a        10 10
```

The `itime==4` has an empty value in `ival`, so in the result, this value were calculated using the previous values `mean(1,2,3)`.

In the `itime==7` I don't really care if the computation includes or not the values imputed by the mean. But both solutions are welcome, cos it has some difference.

```
> mean(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6))
[1] 3.166667
> mean(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6))
[1] 3.4
```

I found an equivalent question here
[Use tidyverse to replace NA with mean of data, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592092/use-tidyverse-to-replace-na-with-mean-of-data-by-group)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the result where each subsequent mean doesn't rely on the previously updated one:

```
nacummean <- function(x) {
    nas  <- is.na(x)
    cs   <- cumsum(replace(x, nas, 0))
    x[nas] <- cs[nas] / (which(nas) - cumsum(nas)[nas])
    x
}

library(dplyr)
ds %>%
    group_by(iname) %>%
    mutate(ival = nacummean(ival))
## A tibble: 10 x 3
## Groups:   iname [1]
#   iname itime  ival
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 a         1   1  
# 2 a         2   2  
# 3 a         3   3  
# 4 a         4   2  
# 5 a         5   5  
# 6 a         6   6  
# 7 a         7   3.4
# 8 a         8   8  
# 9 a         9   9  
#10 a        10  10
```

The logic is: take a cumulative sum along the variable, after replacing `NA` values with `0`, then replace all the `NA`s with the cumsum value at that point, divided by its position in the vector minus the cumulative number of `NA` values.

The other calculation is a bit trickier as it will probably require multiple passes. Here's one attempt using a `while` loop:

```
nacummean_upd <- function(x) {
    while(sum(is.na(x)) > 0) {
        fna <- match(NA,x)
        xs <- head(x, fna)
        x[seq(1,fna)] <- nacummean(xs)
    }
    x
}

library(dplyr)
ds %>%
    group_by(iname) %>%
    mutate(ival = nacummean_upd(ival))
## A tibble: 10 x 3
## Groups:   iname [1]
#   iname itime  ival
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 a         1  1   
# 2 a         2  2   
# 3 a         3  3   
# 4 a         4  2   
# 5 a         5  5   
# 6 a         6  6   
# 7 a         7  3.17
# 8 a         8  8   
# 9 a         9  9   
#10 a        10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

##### scenario 1: doesn't depend on replaced NA values

```r
not_depend <- function(x) {
  na_inds <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na_inds] <- sapply(na_inds, function(y) {
    mean(x[seq_len(y)], na.rm = TRUE)
  })
  x
}

ds %>% mutate(ival = not_depend(ival))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    iname itime  ival
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl>
#>  1 a         1   1  
#>  2 a         2   2  
#>  3 a         3   3  
#>  4 a         4   2  
#>  5 a         5   5  
#>  6 a         6   6  
#>  7 a         7   3.4
#>  8 a         8   8  
#>  9 a         9   9  
#> 10 a        10  10
```

##### scenario 2: Depends on replaced NA values:

```r
depends <- function(x) {
  na_inds <- which(is.na(x))
  sapply(na_inds, function(y){
    x[y] <<- mean(x[seq_len(y)], na.rm = TRUE)
  })
  x
}

ds %>% mutate(ival = depends(ival))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    iname itime  ival
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl>
#>  1 a         1  1   
#>  2 a         2  2   
#>  3 a         3  3   
#>  4 a         4  2   
#>  5 a         5  5   
#>  6 a         6  6   
#>  7 a         7  3.17
#>  8 a         8  8   
#>  9 a         9  9   
#> 10 a        10 10
```